# Press button to start code and press it to stop

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I want to make it so when i push a button it runs this

```
window.setInterval(function(){
               if (recources > 0.5) {
               nuggets = nuggets +  nuggetsPS
               document.getElementById('nuggets').innerHTML = prettify(nuggets);
               }

               }, 1000);
```

and when i push the button again it stops the code.
So basically i want to make the code run when the user pushes the button and stops when they push it again
I am sort of new at Js and need help.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking... I think you're needing clearInterval???

Comment: explain i don't really understand i also edited the question

Comment: Use clearInterval to stop interval timer funciton...

Comment: ok thanks. I looked up clearInterval. its not exactly what i wanted but it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInterval` returns an id that can then be passed to `clearInterval` which will stop the execution. So you can have a function to start the execution, and another to stop it. Something like this:

```
var intervalId;
function startExecution() {
  intervalId = setInterval(function(){
    //do stuff
  },1000);
}

function stopExecution() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  intervalId = 0;
}
```

Then you can bind an event listener to your button to toggle:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
  if (!!intervalId) {
    // If there is a truthy (non-zero) intervalId, start execution
    startExecution();
  } else {
    stopExecution();
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said in the comments, you can use `setInterval` to start an interval and `clearInterval` to stop one.  You pass the return value of the `setInterval` call to the `clearInterval` call, like so:

```
var intervalTracker;
var start = function() {
    intervalTracker = window.setInterval(function(){
       if (recources > 0.5) {
           nuggets = nuggets +  nuggetsPS
           document.getElementById('nuggets').innerHTML = prettify(nuggets);
       }
   }, 1000);
}
var stop = function() {
    window.clearInterval(intervalTracker);
}
```